# Rendering common session information in every view

Tags: python, django, session, templates

I'd like to output some information that depends on session data in Django. Let's take a "Login" / "Logged in as  | Logout" fragment for example. It depends on my `request.session['user']`.

Of course I can put a user object in the context every time I render a page and then switch on `{% if user %}`, but that seems to break DRY idea - I would have to add user to every context in every view.

How can I extract a fragment like that and make it more common?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [template inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) to derive all of your templates from a common base that suitably uses the common parts of the context, and make all your contexts with a factory function that ensures the insertion in them of those common parts.

Comment: I was actually expecting some decorator magic for views... But hey - this solution works too :D

Comment: @viraptor, glad to hear this - I think magic is usually better avoided when something can be accomplished with more focus on simplicity!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make certain areas of your site only accessible when logged on? Or certain areas of a particular page?

If you want to block off access to a whole URL you can use the @login_required decorator in your functions in your view to block certain access. Also, you can use includes to keep the common parts of your site that require user login in a separate html that gets included, that way you're only writing your if statements once.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a context processor that includes logic and place it into a variable you can use in any of your pages without adding it to each call.

See more info at [How to pass common dictionary data to every page in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221592/how-to-pass-common-dictionary-data-to-every-pages-in-django)